# Why can't javascript find a div that is defined below it?

Tags: javascript, html

This works:

```
  <html>
  <body>
  <div id="bla"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
     var mybla = document.getElementById('bla')
  </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

This doesn't:

```
  <html>
  <body>

  <script type="text/javascript">
     var mybla = document.getElementById('bla')
  </script>

  <div id="bla"></div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

mybla is null at this point. argh. How can I make this work? Thanks!!!
(and yes, I want the div below the script)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because the DOM isn't fully loaded yet. You need to put your code in an `onload` handler if you want it above the HTML. Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        var mybla = document.getElementById('bla');
    }
</script>
```